# Can't locate ImageIcon in JButton

Tags: java, icons, jbutton

I am trying to assign a png type image to a JButton which is already created.

I've added a resource folder in the root folder of the project named images.
I've tried to approach it with many ways as similar questions already exists but I can't seem to figure it out...

```
ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon("/images/water.png");
bSquares[pos][line].setIcon(ico);
```

I've also tried many other paths like
The source: 
    ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon("/TelikoDama/images/water.png");

I think it's the paths fault, or maybe my eclipse does not locate it? I don't know.

This is the NPE Im getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at cheeckers.gameUI.initializeGui(gameUI.java:112)
    at cheeckers.gameUI.<init>(gameUI.java:33)
    at cheeckers.gameUI$1.run(gameUI.java:226)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**EDIT**
I found a workaround, I've manually set the path of the folder in the .classpath:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/src/images"/>
```

AND acessed the image like this:

```
Image ico = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/water.png")).getImage();
                        bSquares[pos][line].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico));
```

Comment: are you sure you added the resource folder to the class path? you may post a screenshot of the package explorer view ....

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/dt0sbb9kt/image.jpg

Comment: This has been asked many times before, for example, please see this [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631636/what-is-the-correct-path-to-display-an-imageicon-png-file-for-windows-7) which was used to close your question. And for more similar questions/answers, please check out this [search of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+imageicon+not+working). In fact, this second link is the most important since it will introduce you to the search capabilities of this site and help reduce unnecessary duplicate questions.

Comment: That was me stating that I know that this subject has been asked tho I cant go out and figure it out, wasn't me? I know the search function of the site, this is not the first time I'm in a community like this

Comment: @JoeVox: Please have a look at [how to add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Hope this helps somewhat in your endeavour :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use this code to get the image file for pretty much every components that you find in java UI:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
Image img= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("//images/water.png"));
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Comment: if I init like this I cant set it to an icon, even if I cast it

Comment: @JoeVox: then you create an ImageIcon with the image using the correct constructor. The API will help you here. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I've made changes to the code...I think it should work now :)

Comment: It resonds as: Unhandled type exception type IOException

Comment: @JoeVox: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+Unhandled+type+exception+type+IOException

Comment: you should surround the code in try catch block