# Display image from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a slot machine. I have 3 classes, Symbol,Reel, Gui.
How do I display the images in to the Jlabels? I need to populate the ArrayList in the reel class and use the List in the Gui class to display images in the JLabels.

Answer (score 1):

```
p3.setIcon(listImages.get(2).getIcon());
```

Comment: getting the exception now Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
 at framet.Reel.<init>(Reel.java:17)
 at framet.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:21)
 at framet.Gui.main(Gui.java:53)

Comment: This is because java is having trouble finding the image.  You need to make sure the images are located in the same folder as Reel.java

Comment: they are in the same folder the SRC folder, i have added the screen shot

Comment: You can look at this for help on loading an image from your filesystem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631636/what-is-the-correct-path-to-display-an-imageicon-png-file-for-windows-7

Comment: Ok, finally see your screenshot.  You are trying to load "seven.png"  and the image is called "redseven.png"